# How to get values from a DB and use them for SMTP connector in Mule 3.4

Tags: database, smtp, mule

I would like to read some email details from the DB. Can you help me with this? 
My config xml:

```
<jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="MS_SQL_Data_Source1" user="sa" password="Pa$$w0rd" url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.156;databaseName=Almaty" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>
<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source1" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
<flow name="DCNotifierFlow1" doc:name="DCNotifierFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="myjob" repeatInterval="3600000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job groupName="myjob" jobGroupName="myjob"/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database" connector-ref="Database" queryKey="select">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="procedura1" value="call sp_DataCollectionNotify()"/>
        <jdbc-ee:query key="select" value="select name from aaa"/>
    </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="subject" value="#[map-payload:name]"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.mail.ru" port="465" user="bekbol_shynar%40mail.ru" password="" to="shiko_18@mail.ru" from="bekbol_shynar@mail.ru" subject="${smtp.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>. 
</flow>
```

I have an error: Expression Evaluator "map-payload" with expression "name" returned null but a value was required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I include my config xml and error. I want read email subject and body from DB.

Answer (score 1):

The payload after your JDBC outbound endpoint is a list of maps, not a map, therefore you cannot use map-payload. 
Provided that you got at least 1 row, you can access it like this:

```
#[payload[0]['name']]
```

Comment: It was helpful. Thank you. I have another problem. I have a database table with few lines, but it sends only the first. How can I configure it to send all at the same time different messages?

Comment: If i have more than 1 row, how can I send message?

Comment: Can you put a logger logging the payload after the JDBC outbound and let us know the output?

Comment: I put after JDBC a logger. The output:

Comment: org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=1c4301da-3d2e-11e3-aec3-2791af45c260
  payload=java.util.ArrayList
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Comment: Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    jobConfig=org.mule.transport.quartz.jobs.EventGeneratorJobConfig@7e0cc461
    jobData=org.quartz.JobDataMap@9d0720e2
    queries=merged: {select=select subject, email, body, admin_email from DataCollectionNotify}
    queryTimeout=-1
    repeatInterval=3600000

Comment: INBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.quartz.myjob
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
    MULE_ENDPOINT=jdbc://select
    MULE_ROOT_MESSAGE_ID=1c4301da-3d2e-11e3-aec3-2791af45c260
  SESSION scoped properties:
}

Comment: INFO  2013-10-25 10:44:37,620 [[dcnotifier].DCNotifierFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [{admin_email=, email=sh.askarova@factor.kz, subject=Уведомление, body=Для заливки формы "Цены на социально значимые товары 3" осталось 01:15:23 времени. Пожалуйста, не забудьте залить данные до истечения срока.}, {admin_email=, email=bibo_90@mail.ru, subject=Уведомление, body=Для заливки формы "тест3" осталось 01:15:23 времени. Пожалуйста, не забудьте залить данные до истечения срока.}]

Comment: I tried solve this problem with "For each" scope,but it send only 1 message(second row in the table of DB).

Comment: My config xml:  <foreach counterVariableName="i" batchSize="1000">
            <message-properties-transformer>
                <add-message-property key="toAddresses" value="#[payload[i]['email']]"/>
                <add-message-property key="subject" value="#[payload[i]['subject']]"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465" user="" password="" to="#[payload[i]['toAddresses']]" from="" subject="#[payload[i]['subject']]"/>
        </foreach>

Comment: I tried solve this problem with "For each" scope,but it send only 1 message(second row in the table of DB). My config xml: <foreach counterVariableName="i" batchSize="1000"> <message-properties-transformer> <add-message-property key="toAddresses" value="#[payload[i]['email']]"/> <add-message-property key="subject" value="#[payload[i]['subject']]"/> </message-properties-transformer> <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465" user="" password="" to="#[payload[i]['toAddresses']]" from="" subject="#[payload[i]['subject']]"/> </foreach>

Comment: why no one answers to my question??